# Импорт модулей в Python

Tags: python, библиотеки, sqlalchemy, модули

Есть структура проекта:

```
Programs
- Lib
- - __init__.py
- - dbController.py
- - gLibs.py
- - logCollector.py
- - main.py
- - models.py
- __init__.py
- deploy.py
- Database.db
- Logs.db
- settings.py
```

Когда я работаю в PyCharm, я могу спокойно в файле main.py импортировать gLibs, settings и т.д. просто написав:

```py
import gLibs
import settings
```

И всё работает, всё запускается.
Тогда же, когда я пытаюсь запустить main.py через терминал, находясь в папке Programs:

```
python Lib/main.py
```

Мне выдаёт `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'settings'`.

Я почитал различные решения в интернете, и самым адекватным показалось создать __init__.py в обеих папках: Programs и Lib, но это не помогло.

Я также пробовал заменить `import settings` на `from .. import settings`, на что получил `ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package`, в этот раз как в терминале, так и в PyCharm.

Ещё одним решением я увидел создание файла deploy.py в самой директории Programs

deploy.py:

```py
import sys

if __name__ == "__main__":
    if len(sys.argv) > 1:
        if sys.argv[1] == "Lib":
            from Lib import main
```

В таком варианте он снова начал выдавать ошибки: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gLibs'`. Допустим. Я заменил `import gLibs` на `from Lib import gLibs`. Программа даже запустилась, но начала выдавать ошибки при попытках обратиться к базам данных, что их просто не существует.

**Note:** При запуске из PyCharm всё работает замечательно.

Для работы с базами я использую SQLAlchemy, и само подключение выглядит так:

main.py:

```py
import sys
import sqlalchemy as db
from Lib import gLibs

from Lib.logCollector import logCollector
from Lib.dbController import dbController
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session

import settings

SYSTEM_NAME = "Libs Debugger"
SYSTEM_VERSION = "1.0.0"
try:
    engine = db.create_engine(settings.Database)
    metadata = db.MetaData(engine)
    session = Session(engine, future=True, autoflush=True)
    collector = logCollector()
    controller = dbController(
        SYSTEM_NAME,
        SYSTEM_VERSION,
        engine.connect(),
        session if not settings.individualObjects else Session(engine, future=True, autoflush=True),
        collector if not settings.individualObjects else logCollector()
    )
except Exception as exception:
    print("Произошла ошибка!")
    if hasattr(exception, 'message'):
        print(exception.message if settings.debug else settings.veiledError)
    else:
        print(exception if settings.debug else settings.veiledError)
    sys.exit()
```

в settings.py, соответственно, указаны параметры:

```py
...

# This parameter defines the path to the main database
# Default: "sqlite:///..\\Database.db"
Database: str = "sqlite:///..\\Database.db"

# This parameter defines the path to the log database
# Default: "sqlite:///..\\Logs.db"
Logs: str = "sqlite:///..\\Logs.db"

...
```

Я уже не понимаю, что мне нужно сделать, чтобы оно всё заработало.

Как можно ещё осуществить подключение библиотек, чтобы никакя из частей не считала, что её жестоко обманывают на путь к файлу?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Всё оказалось проще, чем думалось.
Достаточно заменить `"sqlite:///..\\Database.db"` на `"sqlite:///Database.db"`, так как рабочей директорией является папка с непосредственно запускаемым файлом, а не то место, где лежит settings.py, просто при запуске через main.py их директории совпадали, а теперь рабочей папкой является Programs.